# PHP - change behaviour of <?= ?>

Tags: php, escaping, xss, htmlspecialchars

I am developing a web application in php, and have created a small framework tailored to my needs. A part of this framework is a templating engine, where I can feed a list of values into html templates.

In these templates, I rely heavily on constructs like

```
<?= $value ?>
```

where the convention is, that $value must not contain html tags that should be processed as such. With that, I thought I should be able to xss-proof my application by using

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>
```

or

```
<?= htmlentities($value) ?>
```

wherever appropriate.

However, because I required that $value must not contain any html markup, I noticed that I could require every occurrence of  to be escaped, without losing functionality.

Of course, just always calling 'htmlspecialchars' explicitly seems like a ridiculous amount of write overhead, and hence I wondered if there is a way to make this call implicit?

in such a way, that

```
<?= $value ?>
```

will always be equivalent to

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($value) ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a function h(...) that does the same (=calls) htmlspecialchars? I mean it. I'd choose this way instead of hacking down to the core.

Comment: Use a function which sanitizes `$value`?

Comment: Unrelated, but you could add it as a function: `function h($str) { return htmlspecialchars($str); }` and then do `<?= h($value); ?>`. Slick.

Comment: No, you cannot change the behaviour of PHP core language constructs. You'll have to write your own templating engine which has the behaviour you describe. Or, instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use one of the myriad existing templating engines which do exactly that already.

Comment: I don't want to have explicit calls to a sanitation function, because I tend to forget calling them. I can't forget it if it's builtin :)

Comment: Overwriting default php functionality may not be a good idea since sooner or later foreign code may enter your project that does not conform to your chances. I would go another way and add the call to htmltentity as default function of your templating engine. How do you assign variables to it? I once wrote a small template language that basically used `this->view->assign('name',$var)` calls to pass variables to templates and did the escaping in the part of the code before my `assign`ed variables where processed. Would sth. like that be an option for you?

Comment: @MichaelHelwig thanks for your suggestion. However, your method will not work in case a passed value is an array, or a mysql result set. Also, I can safely assume that no foreign code will enter my project within a reasonable lifespan.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin No problems with arrays just check them recursively with `is_string` and/or `is_array`. I've never needed result sets in templates, just the resulting arrays.

Comment: @MichaelHelwig still, I'd rather have an implicit escaping mechanism...

Comment: @MichaelHelwig I realized that you were right - it is unwise to evaluate sql result sets in templates. If you post your suggestion as an answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Did that and expanded the comment a little bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwriting default php functionality may not be a good idea since sooner or later foreign code may enter your project that does not conform to your chances.

I would go another way and add the call to `htmltentities` as default function of your templating engine. How do you assign variables to it? For example, I once wrote a small template engine that basically used `this->view->assign('name',$var)` calls to pass variables to templates and did the escaping in the part of the code before my assigned variables where processed (you could also add a method `$this->view->assignRaw(...)` which really passes raw content without escaping.

Of course, if you pass arrays you will have to work on them recursiveley, also handling the keys. If you pass objects, everything might even get more difficult, since you might not really want to automatically replace values here and cloning them beforehand might get expensive. You still have to be aware of what you are passing into your templates but it saves you from the most common mistakes. Maybe you should have a look how modern template engines like Smarty3 or Twig solve these kind of problems.